# Invalid length of startup packet docker compose postgresql

Tags: linux, fedora, docker, composer, pgadmin

I am trying to install/setup pgadmin4 on a linux fedora 28 machine and when I try running this command

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up`

I get these errors:

`postgres_1        | 2019-05-24 13:50:15.903 UTC [125] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
postgres_1        | 2019-05-24 13:50:15.907 UTC [126] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
postgres_1        | 2019-05-24 13:50:15.912 UTC [127] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
postgres_1        | 2019-05-24 13:50:15.917 UTC [128] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
postgres_1        | 2019-05-24 13:50:15.924 UTC [129] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet`

I can also get this same error to happen when I try connecting to localhost/pgadmin4 which shows a 503 error.

Comment: What should it usually be showing?